# JW player controlbar autohide and play again button

Tags: jwplayer

I am using JW player in a php project. My code is like bellow-

```
<div id="vcontainer" style="width:320px">Loading the player ...</video>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jwplayer("vcontainer").setup({ 
autostart: false, 
controlbar: "bottom", 
file: "http://mysite.net/vid.flv",
image: "screen.jpg",
flashplayer: "player.swf", 
volume: '.$volume.', 
width: '.$width.',
height: '.$height.'
}); 
</script>
```

I want 2 things if possible:

1. controlbar will be shown on mouseover. otherwise, it will be hidden. I have seen this in flowplayer.
2. After completing playback, it shows the embed code, email, etc. options. I don't want to show them. I want to show a "play again" button instead.
   Is these possible?

Answer (score 0):

1) I do not believe it is possible. I wanted the same functionality, but I was told by JWP support staff that this is not supported in the player, and we can not control the controlbar using mouse events.
2) It is showing you those options after playback cos you probably have a plugin called - viral or sharing (i am not sure of the name) setup in jw player. This options are a part of the plugin that is enabled, not JWPlayer. You can remove the plugin to not have this options shown